# How to extract public key from a .der file in SubjectPublicKeyInfo format?

Tags: openssl

I have a public key that appears to be in the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` format. I say "appears" because the only thing I know about this key that it loads a Java application using `X509EncodedKeySpec` which, according to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html) is used for loading keys in `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` format.

I've been unable to parse the file with `openssl` with either `pkcs8`, `x509` or `asn1parse`.

Below is the result of asn1 parse:

```
openssl asn1parse -in public_key.der -inform der

0:d=0  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE          
4:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
17:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
19:d=1  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING
```

Based on that output I've tried extracting the actual key by experimenting with different offsets and lengths then saving it to the .der file:

```
openssl asn1parse -in public_key.der -inform der -offset <> -length <l> -out public_key.der
```

Then I'd feed the output back to `openssl`:

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -nocrypt -in public_key.der
```

But keep getting the same error:

> Error decrypting key 140436029183664:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1338:
>   140436029183664:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:852:
>   140436029183664:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1
>   error:tasn_dec.c:772:Field=version, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO

Update: output of

```
openssl asn1parse -in public_key.der -inform der -strparse 19

0:d=0  hl=4 l= 266 cons: SEQUENCE          
4:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim: INTEGER           :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
265:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
```

Comment: `openssl asn1parse -inform der -in file -dump` doesn't do anything? How long is the file? What does it look like in hex?

Comment: Updated the question with the output of asn1parse

Comment: Try with `-strparse 19`

Comment: Check your extracted publickey with `openssl rsa -pubin -inform der -check -in file`

Comment: Added output of strparse

Comment: openssl rsa -pubin -inform der -check -in private_key.der returns:
Only private keys can be checked

Comment: Hmm....  When I run openssl rsa -pubin -inform der -in <extracted_der>   -out thekey.pem I get "Error loading public key". However, when I run in on the original .der he seems to be processing the key just fine... I'm a little lost.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I made an error the entire `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure is the normal 'bare' public key, that you can use with `openssl rsa -pubin -modulus -inform der -in file`  for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` file can be used with `openssl rsa -pubin -inform der|pem -file inputfile -modulus`.

If it is in binary then use `der`, if it is base64 encoded, use `pem`.

Comment: With OpenSSL 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 22.04, the `-file` argument doesn't work. It should be replaced by `-in`. The full command then becomes: `openssl rsa -pubin -inform der -in inputfile -modulus`